# Problems with installing jdk

Tags: java, windows, java-8, 32-bit

When I want to install JDK8 on my Windows 7 (32 bit)
It installed in

`C://Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_211`

Why is the version 1.8? Shouldn't it be 8?

Comment: Java 1.8 and Java 8 are the same thing.

Comment: just like java 6 is java 1.6

Comment: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/175075/why-is-java-version-1-x-referred-to-as-java-x

Comment: More info about java naming: https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/jdk8-naming-2157130.html

Answer (score 2):

As per [Java version history](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Versioning_change) 1.8 is the developer version number and 8 is the product version number. Both numbers represent the same Java version, this split happened in Java 5:

> Both version numbers "1.5.0" and "5.0" are used to identify this release of the Java 2 Platform Standard Edition. Version "5.0" is the product version, while "1.5.0" is the developer version. The number "5.0" is used to better reflect the level of maturity, stability, scalability and security of the J2SE.

Comment: So why do I use "ArrayList<Integer> arr = new ArrayList<Integer>();" I get error?
Errors are:
Multiple markers at this line
 - Syntax error, parameterized types are only available if source 
  level is 1.5
 - Line breakpoint:Kelas1 [line: 9] - main(String[])
 - Syntax error, parameterized types are only available if source 
  level is 1.5
 - Debug Current Instruction Pointer

Comment: Because you have wrong compiler level selected and you are compiling to Java 1.4 or lower despite running on Java 8. What this has to do with your original question?

Comment: How could I fix it?

Comment: Check your IDE settings.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if it's confusing. 1.8 and 8 are the same.
Check out: https://codenotfound.com/java-download-install-jdk-8-windows.html